# Implement Manchester Encoding on Arduino

Tags: python, c++, arduino, encode

I am trying to program a manchester encoding for my arduino.

This means a 1 bit is represented by 10 and zero is represented by 01.

1111 would be 10101010 in manachester code.

My Program (C++ on Arduino) that encodes the char-array to manchester code looks like:

```
//Output needs to be twice as big as input
    void encodeManchester(char * input, char * output, int size) {
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            for(int p=0; p<2; p++) {
                int pos = i*2+(p);
                output[pos] = 0b00000000;
                for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                    int actval = input[i]>>(7-(j+4*p));
                    if((actval & 0b00000001) == 0b00000001) {
                        output[pos] = output[pos] | (0b10<<(j*2));
                    } else {
                        output[pos] = output[pos] | (0b01<<(j*2));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

My Decoder (Python on PC) Looks like:

```
def manDecode(data):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)/2):
        ret.append(0b00000000);

        for p in range(0, 2):
            print(bin(data[i*2+p]));

            for j in range(0, 4):
                part = (data[i*2+p] >> (6-(j*2))) & 0b11
                if part == 0b10:
                    ret[i] = ret[i] | (0b10000000 >> (j+p*4))
    return ret;
```

But I get strange values in manchester code like: 0b11110000 or 0b1111111. where do they come from?

Answer (score 3):

You have some miss match problems in the indexing of the code between C++ and python.

First, when working with bit operation it's much better to work with `unsigned types` (in this case would be unsigned char), because you avoid a lot of problem caused by sign extended when C++ need to convert to larger type.

The C++ version the only change I make was that, changing the input type to `unsigned char`

```cpp
void encodeManchester(unsigned char* input, unsigned char* output, int size)
```

The python version is:

```python
def manDecode(data):
    ret = []
    for i in range(0, len(data)/2):
        ret.append(0b00000000);

        for p in range(0, 2):
            print(bin(data[i*2+p]));

            for j in range(0, 4):
                part = (data[i*2+p] >> (6-(j*2))) & 0b11
                if part == 0b10:
                    ret[i] = ret[i] | (1 << (j+(1-p)*4))
    return ret;
```

The change was in the line: `ret[i] = ret[i] | (1 << (j+(1-p)*4))` check **(1-p)** instead of **p** this is needed because you are forming the number first the `high nible` then the `low nible` and in the first iteration with the previous version would be `ret[i] | (1 << (0 + 0 * 4))` no shifting anything (changing the `low nible`)